# Webkit javascript debugger - possible to have console and script view open at same time?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, webkit

With widescreen monitors, there's plenty of horizontal screen space.  In the webkit debugger (chrome) I'd like to be able to view both the script window (when stepping through code) and the console window at the same time.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do this - is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the `ESC` key is bound to showing and hiding the console. If you are looking at another panel and hit `ESC` (or click the second-from-left icon in the toolbar row; it looks like a > with some lines next to it), that will layer the console over the panel that you are looking at.

I think that should allow you to run the script debugger more or less side-by-side with the console.

Comment: 2nd visual button at very bottom of window does this too. You'll still have windows lined vertically though, not horizontally as OP would've wanted.

Comment: Ah yes that seems to work.  Only complaint is that it displays one above the other (and my vertical space is limited) - but this is much better - thanks

Comment: If you click the settings gear, you can choose to dock your dev tools to the right of the browser, which will give you more vertical space.